# How would I convert an element of a JSONObject to a single element array?

Tags: java, json, org.json

I am using `org.json.JSONObject` and have a json object defined that was converted from XML.  I want to be able to convert one of the elements of the JSON to a single element array, but am unclear on how to do this.  For example, say I have the following json:

```
{
    "heading": "value",
    "numbers": [1,2,3],
    "onevalarray": "MyVal"
}
```

stored in an `org.json.JSONObject` object.  However, I want the element "onevalarray" to be a single element array:

```
{
    "heading": "value",
    "numbers": [1,2,3],
    "onevalarray": ["MyVal"]
}
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method getJsonArray in the JSONbject object and specify the name of the property in the JSONObject which has the JSONArray in it like this:

Imagine that myJsonObject has this:

```
{"heading": "value", "numbers": [1,2,3], "onevalarray": "MyVal"}
```

And you want a JSONArray with onevalarray data. Try it:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = myJsonObject.getJSONArray("onevalarray");
```

Once you have the value of the onevalarray in the onevalarray JSONArray then remove the onevalarray in the original array and the put it again in this way:

```
myJsonObject.remove("onevalarray");

myJsonObject.put("onevalarray", jsonArray);
```

Comment: But isn't all this going to do is retrieve the "onevalarray" value as an array?  I want that value to be replaced with an array in "myJsonObject so that it looks like:  {"heading": "value", "numbers": [1,2,3], "onevalarray": ["MyVal"]}

Comment: I don't understand sir, can you please show an example of you expected output?

Comment: " I want that value to be replaced with an array in "myJsonObject" well but if actually it is an array in the myJSONObject.

Comment: See both the original posting for the input and output as well as my comment above for an example of the desired output.

Comment: Can't do a "getJSONArray("onevalarray") because it is not an array.  The question is how do I convert the object to an array?